# Is it possible to duplicate a table and transform the new table to a partitioned table

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a partitioned  out of an existing table .

For that i have wrote this query but it seems that my syntax is not correct .

```sql
create table table_Duplicate as
(select * from table)  PARTITION BY RANGE (datecalcul);
```

Notice that  **datecalcul** is a timeStamp column type

My main question that   **(Is it possible to duplicate a postgreSQL table and transform my new table to a partitioned one ?**)

Comment: From PostgreSQL v13 on, you can use logical replication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not create your table first and then insert data into it :

```
-- step 1 - declare table defintion
create table table_Duplicate (
<  copy table structure from table >

) PARTITION BY RANGE (datecalcul);

-- step 2 - declare partitions 
create table tablename_2021 PARTITION OF table_Duplicate
for values from ('2021-01-01') TO ('2021-12-31');

create table tablename_2020 PARTITION OF table_Duplicate
for values from ('2020-01-01') TO ('2020-12-31');

... 


-- step 3 create indexes 

create index on  tablename_2021 (datecalcul);
create index on  tablename_2020 (datecalcul);
...



-- step 4 insert data 
insert into table_Duplicate
select * from table;
```

Comment: Thanks ! the first part of the query is working . But , when i try to integrate data from the none partitioned table (I'm getting an error)  Is it because datecalcul is a tiemstamp field ?

Comment: @Kakoo16 oops missed an important step , see updated answer

Comment: Thanks a lot ! it's working now ! TimeStamp doesn't matter i suppose ?

Comment: @Kakoo16 it does , I just wanted to give you an example , partition  your table by the ranges that makes sense for you scenario and make sure partitions cover all possible ranges in your data